# Getting Macs to authenticate to AD and map home directory

Tags: mac-osx, networking, active-directory

I have a multi-platform environment with Macs and Windows.

I have it now setup where users can log into their Macs authenticating with their user accounts in Active Directory.

I used to have their home directory in AD  mapped and placed as a link on their Dock. It seems to have stopped working and I have no idea where I even set that up since it was such a long time ago.

Can anyone point me in some good documentation to help me achieve getting this map? I would love to have the macs map to other shared drives as well.

Comment: What version of OS X is on the Macs?

Comment: Snow Leopard for the Macs and XServer for the server

Comment: Is the server not Windows?

Comment: XServer is not an operating system, it's Apple's product line of 1U servers. What OS is that running?

Comment: Ah.  I believe it's called an Xserve, to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful links:

- [Best Practices: Integrating Mac OS X with Active Directory](http://seminars.apple.com/pdf/L334436C_ActiveDirect_WP.pdf)
- [Snow Leopard and Active Directory Tips](http://www.macwindows.com/snowleopardAD.html)
- [Network home directory may not mount if bound to Active Directory](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2495)

The first one will tell you where to configure all that in OS X.  The second one will help with all the little issues you'll find along the way (to some extent).  Google will be of help after that.

Good luck!

UPDATE: Now I'm in front of a Mac with Snow Leopard, so I can tell you how to do it here:

- Open System Preferences
- Open the Accounts section
- Click Login Options at the bottom of the accounts pane on the left
- At the bottom of the right pane, there's a Network Account section with an Edit button if you've already set it up.  If you haven't set it up, it'll probably be something like Add.

There will also be some server-side stuff you'll have to do to get the directory to mount.  I've had this Mac bound to the Active Directory server at work for quite a while, but it just recently started to mount my home directory after the server admin made some changes to fix other problems.